# SQL to find articles with ALL of a set of tags

Tags: sql

Finding articles with ANY of a set of tags is a relatively simple join, and has been discussed already: [Best DB (MySQL) structure: Articles which contain favored tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900337/best-db-mysql-structure-articles-which-contain-favored-tags)

But what if I'm searching, and want to find articles with ALL of a set of tags?

For specificity, assume the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
   `id` INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `applied_tags` (
   `tag_id` INT NOT NULL,
   `article_id` INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `search_tags` (
   `search_id` INT NOT NULL,
   `tag_id` TAG NOT NULL
);
```

I came up with this, which I think might work, but it's massive, ugly, and kinda unclear, so I figure there must be a better way:

```
Select articles.id from articles
where
 ( select count(*) from applied_tags
   where applied_tags.article_id == articles.id
     and applied_tags.tag_id in (select search_tags.tag_id from search_tags where search_tags.search_id == <input>) 
     ==
 (select count(*) from search_tags where search_tags.search_id == <input>)
```

(Essentially, count if the number of relevant tags is the expected value.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select article_id
from  applied_tags 
where tag_id in (<input tag set here>)
group by article_id
having count(*) = <count of input tags>
```

This should do it. I won't swear it's the most efficient way, but it will do what you want, assuming that tag_id + article_id is the primary key on applied_tags. If it's not (i.e., you can have duplicate tags) all bets are off.

Comment: Thanks, that's much more elegant.  I think I can speed it up a bit by doing "from (select article_id from applied_tags where tag_id == <one of the tags>)" too.

And yes, I actually have unique indexes for both (tag_id, article_id) and (article_id, tag_id).

Comment: If i have a many-to-many table Actors_Roles, and another table containing a list of Roles and wanted ro find all actors whose roles are all found in Roles, how would these tables above correspond to mine? Would the problem be analogous to start with?

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393019/sql-select-records-with-matching-subsets for another way to put my problem.