# Find all sets/entities that are in another set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subset

The answer is found in the abstract [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066053/find-all-sets-which-are-a-subset-of-a-superset-in-sql/4066450?noredirect=1#comment92981386_4066450) but I'm looking for the concrete SQL solution.

Given the following tables:

```
   ------------     -----------
   |  F_Roles |     | T_Roles | 
   ------+-----     -----+-----
   | FId | RId|     |TId | RId|
   ------+------    -----+-----
   |  f1 |  2 |     | t1 | 1  |
   |  f1 |  3 |     | t1 | 2  |
   |  f2 |  2 |     | t1 | 3  |
   |  f2 |  4 |     | t1 | 4  |
   |  f2 |  9 |     | t1 | 5  |
   |  f3 |  6 |     | t1 | 6  |
   |  f3 |  7 |     | t1 | 7  |
   ------------     ----------
```

(F_Roles) is a join table between F (not shown) and Roles (also not shown)
(T_Roles) is a join table between T (not shown) and Roles (not shown)

I need to return:

1. all (DISTINCT) FId's where the set of RId's for a given FId is a subset of (or 'IN') Roles. (I know I'm mixing Set Theory with database terms but only in the interest of better conveying the idea, I hope). So, f1 and f3 should be returned in this case, because the set of RId's for f1, {2,3}, and for f3, {6,7}, are subsets of T_Roles.
2. the list of RId's in T_Roles NOT found in any of the functions returned above. (T_Roles - (f1 Union f3)),  or {1,4,5} in this example.

Comment: Please confirm (edit your question): a) `F` is a table not shown ? b) `F_Roles` is an associative table (`F`::`Roles`) that has no integrity [eg. there is no RID 9 in `Roles`] ? c) which you are trying to determine, in order to correct it. ? I would not use the term 'subset' here, just `IN`.

Comment: In my actual problem, the Roles dataset shown above is a subset of a Something-Else_Roles many-to-many table/relationship. I tried to simplify it here. I'm not sure of the properties of associative table but yes, there is not referential integrity between F_Roles and Roles.

Comment: Thanks, you have cleaned up the question.  Ok, you have two Associative files.  But there is still some clean-up to be done.  In [1][2], please do not refer to files that are not shown.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define the following sample data:

```
DECLARE @F_Roles TABLE
(
    [FID] CHAR(2)
   ,[RID] TINYINT
);

DECLARE @Roles TABLE
(
    [RID] TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO @F_Roles ([FID], [RID])
VALUES ('f1', 2)
      ,('f1', 3)
      ,('f2', 2)
      ,('f2', 4)
      ,('f2', 9)
      ,('f3', 6)
      ,('f3', 7);

INSERT INTO @Roles ([RID])
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7);
```

No, the first query can be solved using the T-SQL statement below:

```
SELECT F.[FID] 
FROM @F_Roles F
LEFT JOIN @Roles R
    ON F.[RID] = R.[RID]
GROUP BY F.[FID]
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN R.[RID] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = COUNT(F.[RID]);
```

The idea is pretty simple. We are using `LEFT` join in order to check which `RID` from the `@F_Roles` table has corresponding `RID` in the `@Roles`table. If it has not, the value returned by the query for the corresponding row is `NULL`. So, we just need to count the `RIDs` for each `FID` and to check if this count is equal to the count of values returned by the second table (`NULL` values are ignored).

The latter query is simple, too. Having the `FID` from the first, we just can use `EXCEPT` in order to found `RIDs` which are not matched:

```
SELECT [RID]
FROM @Roles
EXCEPT
SELECT [RID]
FROM @F_Roles
WHERE [FID] IN
(
    SELECT F.[FID] 
    FROM @F_Roles F
    LEFT JOIN @Roles R
        ON F.[RID] = R.[RID]
    GROUP BY F.[FID]
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN R.[RID] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = COUNT(F.[RID])
);
```

Here is the result of the execution of the queries:

[image]

Comment: Masterfully explained!

Comment: This solution needs updating after I've changed the question to be more clear. Apologies, @gotqn

Answer (score 0):

For query 1:

```
with x as (
select f.fid, sum(case when r.rid is null then 1 end) as missing
  from f_roles f
  left join roles r on r.rid = r.rid
  group by f.fid
)
select distinct f.fid
  from f_roles f
  join x on f.fid = x.fid
  where x.missing = 0
```

For query 2:

```
with x as (
select f.fid, sum(case when r.rid is null then 1 end) as missing
  from f_roles f
  left join roles r on r.rid = r.rid
  group by f.fid
),
y as (
select distinct f.fid
  from f_roles f
  join x on f.fid = x.fid
  where x.missing = 0
)
select r.rid
  from roles r 
  where r.rid not in (
    select f.rid from y join f_roles f on f.rid = y.rid
  )
```