# sql select records with matching subsets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There are two sets of employees: managers and grunts.
For each manager, there's a table manager_meetings that holds a list of which meetings each manager attended.  A similar table grunt_meetings holds a list of which meetings each grunt attended.

So:

```
manager_meetings                          grunt_meetings
managerID      meetingID                  gruntID        meetingID
1              a                          4              a
1              b                          4              b
1              c                          4              c
2              a                          4              d
2              b                          5              a 
3              c                          5              b
3              d                          5              c
3              e                          6              a 
                                          6              c 
                                          7              b 
                                          7              a
```

The owner doesn't like it when a manager and a grunt know exactly the same information.  It makes his head hurt.  He wants to identify this situation, so he can demote the manager to a grunt, or promote the grunt to a manager, or take them both golfing.  The owner likes to golf.

The task is to list every combination of manager and grunt where both attended exactly the same meetings.  If the manager attended more meeting than the grunt, no match.  If the grunt attended more meetings than the manager, no match.

The expected results here are:

```
ManagerID            GruntID
2                    7
1                    5
```

...because manager 2 and grunt 7 both attended (a,b), while manager 1 and grunt 5 both attended (a,b,c).

I can solve it in a clunky way, by pivoting up the subset of meetings in a subquery into XML, and comparing each grunt's XML list to each manager's XML.  But that's horrible, and also I have to explain to the owner what XML is.  And I don't like golfing.

Is there some better way to do `"WHERE {subset1} = {subset2}"`?  It feels like I'm missing some clever kind of join.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ce50/1)

Comment: Well, +1 for the SQL Fiddle, an interesting back story, an attempt to solve it yourself, and a challenging question. If only all questions could be this thorough!

Comment: Oh, but -1 for [using `char` without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx). :-)

Comment: No lengthless char declarations in my production code, I promise!  Took a couple shortcuts while obscuring the code.

Comment: I didn't actually -1 just wanted to mention the bad habit for any readers.

Comment: [Similar question on the dba site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/45302/3690). IMO The XML method is perfectly reasonable!

Answer (score 8):

Here is a version that works:

```
select m.mId, g.gId, count(*) --select m.mid, g.gid, mm.meetingid, gm.meetingid as gmm
from manager m cross join
     grunt g left outer join
     (select mm.*, count(*) over (partition by mm.mid) as cnt
      from manager_meeting mm
     ) mm
     on mm.mid = m.mId full outer join
     (select gm.*, count(*) over (partition by gm.gid) as cnt
      from grunt_meeting gm
     ) gm
     on gm.gid = g.gid and gm.meetingid = mm.meetingid 
group by m.mId, g.gId, mm.cnt, gm.cnt
having count(*) = mm.cnt and mm.cnt = gm.cnt;
```

The string comparison method is shorter, perhaps easier to understand, and probably faster.

EDIT:

For your particular case of getting exact matches, the query can be simplified:

```
select mm.mId, gm.gId
from (select mm.*, count(*) over (partition by mm.mid) as cnt
      from manager_meeting mm
     ) mm join
     (select gm.*, count(*) over (partition by gm.gid) as cnt
      from grunt_meeting gm
     ) gm
     on gm.meetingid = mm.meetingid and
        mm.cnt = gm.cnt
group by mm.mId, gm.gId
having count(*) = max(mm.cnt);
```

This might be more competitive with the string version, both in terms of performance and clarity.

It counts the number of matches between a grunt and a manager.  It then checks that this is all the meetings for each.

Comment: +1 nice answer. I went off on a tangent trying to do something clever with EXCEPT / INTERSECT or CROSS APPLY and quickly felt defeated.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . I was able to improve it a bit.

Answer (score 4):

An attempt at avenging [Aaron's defeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393019/sql-select-records-with-matching-subsets#comment32268676_21393510) – a [solution using EXCEPT](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ce50/7):

```
SELECT
  m.mID,
  g.gID
FROM
  manager AS m
INNER JOIN
  grunt AS g
ON  NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT meetingID
  FROM   manager_meeting
  WHERE  mID = m.mID
  EXCEPT
  SELECT meetingID
  FROM   grunt_meeting
  WHERE  gID = g.gID
)
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT meetingID
  FROM   grunt_meeting
  WHERE  gID = g.gID
  EXCEPT
  SELECT meetingID
  FROM   manager_meeting
  WHERE  mID = m.mID
);
```

Basically, subtract a grunt's set of meetings from a manager's set of meetings, then the other way round. If neither result contains rows, the grunt and the manager attended the same set of meetings.

Please note that this query will match managers and grunts that never attended a single meeting.

Comment: Wonderful.  I started down this road of INTERSECT/EXCEPT too, but like Aaron I gave up after a few nested versions of "A does not not contain B or B contains A but not C" kind of thing.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative version - but requires another table. Basically, we give each meeting a distinct power of two as it's 'value', then sum every manager's meeting value and each grunt's meeting value. Where they're the same, we have a match.

It should be possible to make the `meeting_values` table a TVF, but this is a little bit simpler.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c63fa/1/0)

Additional table:

```
CREATE TABLE meeting_values (value INT, meetingID CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO meeting_values VALUES
 (1,'a'),(2,'b'),(4,'c'),(8,'d'),(16,'e');
```

And the query:

```
SELECT managemeets.mID, gruntmeets.gID
FROM
    ( SELECT gm.gID, sum(value) AS meeting_totals
      FROM grunt_meeting gm 
             INNER JOIN 
       meeting_values mv ON gm.meetingID = mv.meetingID
      GROUP BY gm.gID 
    ) gruntmeets 
     INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT mm.mID, sum(value) AS meeting_totals
      FROM manager_meeting mm 
             INNER JOIN 
           meeting_values mv ON mm.meetingID = mv.meetingID
      GROUP BY mm.mID 
    ) managemeets ON gruntmeets.meeting_totals = managemeets.meeting_totals
```

Comment: Clever approach, although we'd run out powers of two pretty quickly.  Although I'd love to tell people, "We can't have any more meetings; we've already had 63."