# SQL Complex Query with Lookup in 2nd Table based on 1st Table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I've been thinking about how to do this for almost 2 days now and still to no avail. I'd appreciate it if anybody could give me pointers or help me to do this SQL statement. So I have these tables...

```
Table1  
NameField

Mark
John
Chris
Tina
Charles

Table2
NameField    ItemField

Mark         Pencil
Mark         Bag
Mark         Paper
Mark         Book
John         Book
John         Ballpen
Chris        Bag
Chris        Paper
Chris        Pencil
Tina         Ballpen
Charles      Computer
Charles      Book
Charles      Pencil
Charles      Box
Charles      Shoes
```

How do  I make the SQL statement that queries for data based on these conditions?

a) Get all `NameField` from `Table1` where `ItemField` has `Bag` AND `Paper` AND `Pencil`.

Result:

```
    Chris
```

b) Get all `NameField` from `Table1` where `ItemField` has `Bag` AND `Paper` AND `Pencil` with extra 0 or 1 or 2 extra random `ItemField`.

Result:

```
    Mark, Chris
```

c) Get all `NameField` from `Table1` where `ItemField` has `Pencil` regardless if `ItemField` has other items and count the extra items(excluding item `Pencil`) and list the extra items.

Result:

```
    Mark - 3 - Bag, Paper, Book
    Chris - 2 - Bag, Paper
    Charles - 4 - Computer, Book, Box, Shoes
```

I have tried doing this with the help of a server side scripting language by looping through each `NameField` in `Table1` and then looping again for each `ItemField`. So if I had 1000 items under `Table` I would need to loop through 1000 items. The solution was ridiculously inefficient. So I'm sorry if I couldn't put any code I had so far for this because I honestly don't have one. Nothing pops out. This is the first problem like this that I have encountered. Thank you very much.

Comment: None* of these queries require Table1 since NameField exists in Table 2.

Comment: Put up a fiddle at sqlfiddle.com and I'll help you out.

Comment: @Devon Yes Sir... I'm making it now...

Comment: You need one query to satisfy all three conditions, or three queries?

Comment: @MikeParkhill 3 queries Sir :)

Comment: That's a relief.  Did you get that fiddle up?

Comment: @MikeParkhill Hold on Sir, I have the SQL to create and insert... but I'm having problem with SQLFiddle, just a sec :)

Comment: Here Sir :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31b7b/2

Comment: Is this for mysql, or SQLServer?

Comment: @AdamWenger Either Sir, I use both :)

Comment: `a` has [an existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400451/sql-to-find-articles-with-all-of-a-set-of-tags), and you can trivially adapt it for `b` as well.  `c` is a slightly different answer - you actually have multiple questions here (too broad).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse How can this be too broad when I have exactly specified everything?

Comment: See how the answers have more than one query for different things?  Yeah.  You've got a nice level of specificity, which means it's not unclear.

Comment: Do all questions that are posted here have to have only 1 answer? Is that a rule here? I mean you're the better one here. So I'm just asking.

Comment: Thank you for your comment anyway. These people here helped me get the answer I wanted, so I'm thankful to them I'm good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave it a shot, only using Table2.

1)

```
SELECT a.NameField, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT b.ItemField) AS MatchCount, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.ItemField) AS TotalCount, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.ItemField) AS MatchedItems,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.ItemField) AS AllItems
FROM Table2 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b
  ON b.NameField = a.NameField
  AND b.ItemField IN ('Bag', 'Paper', 'Pencil')
GROUP BY a.NameField
HAVING TotalCount = 3 AND MatchCount = 3;
```

2)

```
SELECT a.NameField, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT b.ItemField) AS MatchCount, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.ItemField) AS TotalCount, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.ItemField) AS MatchedItems,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.ItemField) AS AllItems
FROM Table2 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b
  ON b.NameField = a.NameField
  AND b.ItemField IN ('Bag', 'Paper', 'Pencil')
GROUP BY a.NameField
HAVING MatchCount >= 3;
```

3)

```
SELECT a.NameField, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT b.ItemField) AS OtherItemCount, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.ItemField) AS OtherItems
FROM Table2 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b
  ON b.NameField = a.NameField
  AND b.ItemField != 'Pencil'
WHERE a.ItemField = 'Pencil'
GROUP BY a.NameField;
```

It does require putting in the number of items you're matching, but hope it helps!

Edit: [Here's a fiddle - would be fun to see this improved upon!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da61c/1)

Comment: Thank you very much for this help Sir, will try this and report to you as soon as possible :)

Comment: Thank you very much for this Sir. I'm still trying to understand every bit of it with the help of sqlfiddle :)

Comment: +1 since Query C looks like what he wanted.  Query A + B only needed the namefield though, thus could be simpler.

Comment: @pssdbt Upvoted and marked your answer Sir. Thank you very much for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

Query A is pretty easy so I'll start with that:

```
SELECT Namefield FROM Table2 
WHERE ItemField IN ('Bag', 'Paper', 'Pencil')
GROUP BY NameField
HAVING count(*) = 3;
```

Query B: Using the same query as above in a subquery but checking that the overall item count is less than or equal to 5 (allow for 0,1,2 extra)

```
SELECT Namefield FROM Table2 
WHERE NameField IN 
(SELECT Namefield FROM Table2 WHERE ItemField IN ('Bag', 'Paper', 'Pencil') GROUP BY NameField HAVING count(*) = 3) 
GROUP BY NameField 
HAVING count(*) <= 5;
```

Query C: I think pssdbt has the best result for that.  Note though that something that includes multiple items like that should probably be handled by the server side language rather than SQL.  SQL is a flat representation of data.

Comment: The problem with that is it includes anyone who has one of any of those items, and also doesn't exclude anyone who has more than just those items.

Comment: Yeah I tried it. @pssdbt is right. But still, thank you for this.

Comment: @pssdbt you're right I missed the having.

Comment: @chris_techno25 it should work now, I forgot to include the having count(*) so it matches all of them.

Comment: @Devon Yup Sir :) I'm currently experimenting changing your statements with my not-so-helpful ideas. I'm just trying to use different statements if they return the same results. Thank you. I really appreciate it. I'll update after I understand everything :)

Comment: @Devon Upvoted your answer but I'm going to choose pssdbt's answer. Appreciate it just as much :) Thank you Sir!

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different take to everyone else but it does require some up-front work in the form of making the checking string alphabatical.
The good thing about my query is that it supports multiple count of the same item, such as getting 3 pencil & 2 bag.

(inspired by @pssdbt 's answer)

Query A:

```
SELECT NameField, GROUP_CONCAT(ItemField ORDER BY ItemField) AS MatchedItems 
FROM Table2
GROUP BY NameField
HAVING MatchedItems = "Bag,Paper,Pencil";
```

Query B:

```
SELECT NameField, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ItemField ORDER BY ItemField) AS MatchedItems ,
count(ItemField) as totalCount 
FROM Table2
GROUP BY NameField
HAVING MatchedItems LIKE "%Bag%Paper%Pencil%" AND totalCount <= 5;
```

Query C:

```
SELECT NameField, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT if(ItemField="Pencil",null,ItemField) ORDER BY ItemField) AS MatchedItems, 
  SUM(if(ItemField="Pencil",0,1)) as extraCount,
  SUM(if(ItemField="Pencil",1,0)) as hasPencil
FROM Table2
GROUP BY NameField
HAVING hasPencil > 0;
```